# Finding a series that is "less" than the original series for comparison test

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have this series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{2n+2}{\sqrt{n^3 +n^2 +n} } $$
I was able to conclude that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{2}{n^{1/2}} < \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{2n+2}{\sqrt{n^3 +n^2 +n}}$$
Which clearly implies that the original series is divergent by the Comparison Test. However, I want to ask if my steps are (unconditionally) valid to arrive to that $p$-series. See the steps below:
$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{n^3 +n^2 +n}} < \frac{2n}{\sqrt{n^3 +n^2 +n}} + \frac{2}{\sqrt{n^3 +n^2 +n}}= \frac{2n+2}{\sqrt{n^3 +n^2 +n} }$$
$$\iff \frac{2}{\sqrt{n(n^2 +n +1)}} < \frac{2}{n^{1/2}} < \frac{2n+2}{\sqrt{n^3 +n^2 +n}}$$
By removing the $\dfrac{2n}{\sqrt{n^3 +n^2 +n}}$ term, clearly the resulting term $\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{n^3 +n^2 +n}}$ is less than the original one. But if I remove the factor $\sqrt{n^2 +n +1}$ from its denominator (to produce $\dfrac{2}{n^{1/2}}$, greater), am I *guaranteed* that that $p$-series is less than $\dfrac{2n+2}{\sqrt{n^3 +n^2 +n}}$ by virtue of the removal of $\dfrac{2n}{\sqrt{n^3 +n^2 +n}}$? Or it just happened to be less than the original one? I'm thinking if it's possible that along the process of finding a series that is less than (or greater) than the original series for comparison test, I would arrive otherwise.

Comment: First decide which terms are essential. In this case $2n$ in the numerator and $n^3$ under the square root in the denominator. Then use ${2n+2\over\sqrt{n^3+n^2+n}}\ge {2n\over \sqrt{n^3+n^3+n^3}}.$